# SwiftUI: Prevent word break for long words

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

How do I prevent word breaking for long words, e.g adjust font size to fit width?

Requirements:
The outer gray frame must have the same fixed size.
The should be 2 lines.

```
var body: some View {
VStack {
    Spacer()

    Image(systemName: "square")

                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        
        Spacer()
        Text("Acknowledgement for the rest")
            .allowsTightening(true)
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
            .lineLimit(2)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        
    }
    .padding()
    .frame(width: 140, height: 150, alignment: .center)
    .background(
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .foregroundColor(Color(hex: "f9f9f9"))
        }
    )
```

}

[image]

Comment: Remove Spacer() between image and text, and instead give bottom padding to ImageView and try.

Answer (score 2):

use ***fixedSize*** **modifier**:

---

[image]

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            
            Image(systemName: "square")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            
            Spacer()
            Text("Acknowledgement for the rest")
                .fixedSize()    // <<: Here
                .allowsTightening(true)
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
                .lineLimit(nil)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(height: 150)
        .background(
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            }
        )
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, the size for the background cannot change, 
.frame(width: 140, height: 150, alignment: .center)

Comment: then do not change it! use any size what you want, what is issue? when you want prevent word breaking, then you have to give enough space to it as well!

Comment: The text coming in is dynamic. Is might be very long or very short. I want to adjust the font size to fit.

Comment: Aha, you want change font size depending on the frame size! But that is another question or issue! for your question in topic, I just gave right answer I think.

Comment: My bad, I added some clarifications to the question

Answer (score 0):

as you mention in the comment

> The text coming in is dynamic. Is might be very long or very short. I
> want to adjust the font size to fit.

it will adjust the font size to fit the width.[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var acknowledgementString = "acknowledgement for the rest"
let mainWidth : CGFloat = 350//140
var body: some View  {
    Text(acknowledgementString)
        .font(.system(size: 100))
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
        .lineLimit(1)
        .frame(width: mainWidth,height: mainWidth,alignment: .center )
        .background(Color.red)
        .onTapGesture {
            acknowledgementString += " extra"
        }
   } 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is what I'm after, but it should work with multiply lines.

Comment: then just change the lineLimit(1) to lineLimit(2) and it will be on two lines.

Comment: Then your suggestion is not working unfortunately.

Comment: it would be really help full if you can add a gif of some sort, so i can understand the behaviour you require.